# Differences of MySQL locking for update with WHERE and IN

Tags: mysql, locking

So I have a table with `id` as `INT NOT NULL` as the `PK`. When I do query 1 (**Trans1**) in a transaction I get 3 rows locked, and when I do query 2 (**Trans2**) also in a transaction, I do also get 3 rows locked.

Example Table:

```
+----+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+
| id | some_val                             | created_at              |
+----+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+
|  1 | 33aa186d-e2de-4c41-aa50-000000000001 | 2019-03-17 15:15:21.130 |
|  2 | 33aa186d-e2de-4c41-aa50-000000000002 | 2019-03-17 15:15:31.292 |
|  3 | 33aa186d-e2de-4c41-aa50-000000000003 | 2019-03-17 15:16:01.396 |
+----+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

**Trans1**:

```sql
SELECT * FROM example WHERE id >= 1 AND id <= 3 FOR UPDATE;
```

INNODB Status

```
---TRANSACTION 10750, ACTIVE 4 sec
3 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 4 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 23, OS thread handle 0x7f41f5153700, query id 11504 172.19.0.1 root
```

**Trans2**:

```sql
SELECT * FROM example WHERE id IN (1,2,3) FOR UPDATE;
```

INNODB Status

```
---TRANSACTION 10854, ACTIVE 11 sec
2 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 3 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 23, OS thread handle 0x7f41f5153700, query id 11652 172.19.0.1 root
```

Now, even though the results seem similar, they are quite different in regarding of what's actually locked. For starter, no inserts are possible while **Trans1** is in progress, while inserts are possible during **Trans2**. Also, if table has only 3 rows, how is INNODB showing 4 locks (I guess is the next auto increment, thus no inserts possible).

I would like to understand why does this happen, as I've read about gap locking and next-key lock, but none makes sense about what's happening on **Trans1**.

Comment: Sounds similar to this bug I wrote years ago https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-6063 which has a good response from Jan. I assume id is a PK?

Comment: It is PK, yes... So basically mysql has no clue about the PK data type (int) and it's afraid of an insert with id `1.5`, is that it? I still don't get it as both queries are of type `range`, and the result-set is pretty damn straight forward on both cases.

Comment: Is `id` `AUTO_INCREMENT`?  Was there mention of "gap" in the status for one but not the other?  Were you trying to insert id=4?  Does the problem occur if you 'lock' only 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we use the [performance_schema.data_locks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-perfschema-excerpt/8.0/en/data-locks-table.html) table we get a better idea which locks are different.

Here we can see the `supremum`, or [gap lock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-gap-locks) is the additional lock occurs with the RANGE query. While the is possible to avoid because because id 3 exists as a primary key, the MySQL developers haven't implemented this as it complicates locking and adds checks in a rather critical and time sensitive execution path.

Note, setting `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;` will make locks equivalent as gap locks are only `REPEATABLE READ`.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  `id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `some_val` VARCHAR(36),
  `created_at` datetime
);

INSERT INTO example
  (`id`, `some_val`, `created_at`)
VALUES
  ('1', '33aa186d-e2de-4c41-aa50-000000000001', '2019-03-17 15:15:21.130'),
  ('2', '33aa186d-e2de-4c41-aa50-000000000002', '2019-03-17 15:15:31.292'),
  ('3', '33aa186d-e2de-4c41-aa50-000000000003', '2019-03-17 15:16:01.396');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
BEGIN;
```

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT * FROM example WHERE id >= 1 AND id <= 3 FOR UPDATE;

| id  | some_val                             | created_at          |
| --- | ------------------------------------ | ------------------- |
| 1   | 33aa186d-e2de-4c41-aa50-000000000001 | 2019-03-17 15:15:21 |
| 2   | 33aa186d-e2de-4c41-aa50-000000000002 | 2019-03-17 15:15:31 |
| 3   | 33aa186d-e2de-4c41-aa50-000000000003 | 2019-03-17 15:16:01 |
```

---

**Query #3**

```
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.data_locks;

| ENGINE | ENGINE_LOCK_ID | ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID | THREAD_ID | EVENT_ID | OBJECT_SCHEMA | OBJECT_NAME | PARTITION_NAME | SUBPARTITION_NAME | INDEX_NAME | OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN | LOCK_TYPE | LOCK_MODE | LOCK_STATUS | LOCK_DATA              |
| ------ | -------------- | --------------------- | --------- | -------- | ------------- | ----------- | -------------- | ----------------- | ---------- | --------------------- | --------- | --------- | ----------- | ---------------------- |
| INNODB | 2070:1063      | 2070                  | 48        | 4        | test          | example     |                |                   |            | 140108678336728       | TABLE     | IX        | GRANTED     |                        |
| INNODB | 2070:2:4:2     | 2070                  | 48        | 4        | test          | example     |                |                   | PRIMARY    | 140108678333688       | RECORD    | X         | GRANTED     | 1                      |
| INNODB | 2070:2:4:1     | 2070                  | 48        | 4        | test          | example     |                |                   | PRIMARY    | 140108678334032       | RECORD    | X         | GRANTED     | supremum pseudo-record |
| INNODB | 2070:2:4:3     | 2070                  | 48        | 4        | test          | example     |                |                   | PRIMARY    | 140108678334032       | RECORD    | X         | GRANTED     | 2                      |
| INNODB | 2070:2:4:4     | 2070                  | 48        | 4        | test          | example     |                |                   | PRIMARY    | 140108678334032       | RECORD    | X         | GRANTED     | 3                      |
```

---

**Query #4**

```
ROLLBACK;
```

---

**Query #5**

```
BEGIN;
```

---

**Query #6**

```
SELECT * FROM example WHERE id IN (1,2,3) FOR UPDATE;

| id  | some_val                             | created_at          |
| --- | ------------------------------------ | ------------------- |
| 1   | 33aa186d-e2de-4c41-aa50-000000000001 | 2019-03-17 15:15:21 |
| 2   | 33aa186d-e2de-4c41-aa50-000000000002 | 2019-03-17 15:15:31 |
| 3   | 33aa186d-e2de-4c41-aa50-000000000003 | 2019-03-17 15:16:01 |
```

---

**Query #7**

```
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.data_locks;

| ENGINE | ENGINE_LOCK_ID | ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID | THREAD_ID | EVENT_ID | OBJECT_SCHEMA | OBJECT_NAME | PARTITION_NAME | SUBPARTITION_NAME | INDEX_NAME | OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN | LOCK_TYPE | LOCK_MODE | LOCK_STATUS | LOCK_DATA |
| ------ | -------------- | --------------------- | --------- | -------- | ------------- | ----------- | -------------- | ----------------- | ---------- | --------------------- | --------- | --------- | ----------- | --------- |
| INNODB | 2071:1063      | 2071                  | 48        | 9        | test          | example     |                |                   |            | 140108678336728       | TABLE     | IX        | GRANTED     |           |
| INNODB | 2071:2:4:2     | 2071                  | 48        | 9        | test          | example     |                |                   | PRIMARY    | 140108678333688       | RECORD    | X         | GRANTED     | 1         |
| INNODB | 2071:2:4:3     | 2071                  | 48        | 9        | test          | example     |                |                   | PRIMARY    | 140108678333688       | RECORD    | X         | GRANTED     | 2         |
| INNODB | 2071:2:4:4     | 2071                  | 48        | 9        | test          | example     |                |                   | PRIMARY    | 140108678333688       | RECORD    | X         | GRANTED     | 3         |
```

---

**Query #8**

```
ROLLBACK;
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)